# In emacs, how would I replace all accents in a block of text?

Tags: emacs

Suppose I've got:

“Aliud est grâtiam habêre, aliud grâtiam referre. Nôn omnês quî tibi prô beneficiîs grâtiäs agunt, ipsî posteâ, sî opus fuerit, grâtiam tibi referent. Facile est grâtiäs agere prô beneficiîs, nec vërô quidquam difficilius esse vidētur quam beneficiôrum meminisse.”

But I want

“Aliud est grātiam habēre, aliud grātiam referre. Nōn omnēs quī tibi prō beneficiīs grātiās agunt, ipsī posteā, sī opus fuerit, grātiam tibi referent. Facile est grātiās agere prō beneficiīs, nec vērō quidquam difficilius esse vidētur quam beneficiōrum meminisse.”

I.e. â ä -> ā, etc ëê -> ē, etc

I'm thinking a big keyboard macro doing lots of search and replaces, but is there a better way?

Comment: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/tr

Comment: But I would just select the text and use `shell-command-on-region` (`M-|`) with `sed 'y/âäêëîô/āāēēīō/'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many cases it saves a lot of time writing Emacs lisp functions instead of storing kbd-macros etc. Emacs comes with excellent debugging tools. For example call <kbd>M-x edebug-eval-top-level-form RET</kbd>  at your example with solution below:

```
(defun accent-replace ()
  "Does what I want"
  (interactive "*")
  (dolist (ele (list ?â ?ä ?ê ?ë ?î ?ô))
    (setq elt (char-to-string ele))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward elt nil t 1)
      (replace-match
       (char-to-string
    (pcase ele
      (`?â ?ā)
      (`?ä ?ā)
      (`?ê ?ē)
      (`?ë ?ē)
      (`?î ?ī)
      (`?ô ?ō)))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the comments, I came up with this interactive command:

```
(defun tr (from to beg end)
  "Replace each character in FROM with the character at the same position in TO.
Operates from BEG to END, or within the marked region if called interactively.

If TO is shorter than FROM, any characters in FROM beyond the length of TO are
just deleted."
  (interactive "sTranslate from: \nsTranslate to: \nr")
  (goto-char beg)
  (setq end (copy-marker end))
  (let ((regexp (regexp-opt (mapcar 'string from))))
    (while (search-forward-regexp regexp end t)
      (let* ((index (cl-search (match-string 0) from))
             (replace-with (if (> (1+ index) (length to))
                               ""
                             (substring to index (1+ index)))))
        (setf (buffer-substring (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)) replace-with)))))
```

Mark the region that contains the text, call `M-x tr`, and pass `âäëê` as the first string and `āāēē` as the second string.